# First step of creating first app in Android Studio

Tags: kotlin

I tried to "Build & Refresh" in an Android Studio.
Then, it says

1. Dependency 'androidx.core:core:1.12.0-alpha01' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against codename "UpsideDownCake" of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Recommended action: Use a different version of dependency 'androidx.core:core:1.12.0-alpha01',
   or set compileSdkPreview to "UpsideDownCake" in your build.gradle
   file if you intend to experiment with that preview SDK.
2. Dependency 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0-alpha01' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against codename "UpsideDownCake" of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Recommended action: Use a different version of dependency 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0-alpha01',
   or set compileSdkPreview to "UpsideDownCake" in your build.gradle
   file if you intend to experiment with that preview SDK.

I would really appreciate it if you could understand this situation and give me an advice.

Sincerely,
kirara

Comment: The messages from Android Studio already tell you what the problem is and what you should do. You've pulled in some dependencies that require a higher `compileSdkVersion` than what you're using, so you need to either compile against the lastest (preview) SDK, or switch to older versions of those dependencies.